Docker container cannot send mail on multi-homed host
I have a Docker host with two IP addresses (call them A and B). Apache is bound to A, which resolves to web.mydomain.com, while Postfix is bound to B on mail.mydomain.com.
The Docker application is designed to send out mail over SMTP-AUTH to mail.mydomain.com. It also has a web UI that listens on localhost:3000 (shown by docker ps as 127.0.0.1:3000->3000/tcp). This is proxied via Apache to the outside world on web.mydomain.com.
The container appears to be able to resolve the correct DNS requests from the host for A (.59) and B (.83):
nextjs@5b3fccbf323a:/app$ getent hosts 182.xx.xx.59
182.xx.xx.59    mail.mydomain.com

nextjs@5b3fccbf323a:/app$ getent hosts 182.xx.xx.83
182.xx.xx.83    www.mydomain.com

But when I try connecting to the mail port (from inside the container), nothing happens until it times out:
openssl s_client -connect mail.mydomain.com:587 -starttls smtp
Connecting from the host is fine. Other Docker containers running other apps can send out mail in the same way no problem.
I know very little about Docker networking. The connection on port 587 from the container appears to go to the web IP A, but I'm not sure. The web UI on A functions normally. How can I persuade the container to connect to interface A for the web and interface B for SMTP submission?
tcpdump shows packets on port 587 coming from the container, but not coming back from the mail server:
14:30:53.168711 br-36bedc370406 In  ifindex 102 02:42:ac:1f:00:02 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 80: 172.31.0.2.55954 > 185.x.x.59.587: Flags [S], seq 1208255870, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 241634928 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

iptables-save (fail2ban rules omitted):
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Tue Jun 25 14:37:41 2024
*filter
:INPUT DROP [162608:8659146]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [31071143:38820437864]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
:LOGGING - [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i docker0 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -m geoip --source-country GB,UG,KE,ZA  -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 1024:65535 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 12000:13000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 12000:13000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,110,143,465,587,993,995,2525,2526 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,873 -m geoip --source-country GB  -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 8080,3100 -m geoip --source-country GB  -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-36bedc370406 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-36bedc370406 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-36bedc370406 ! -o br-36bedc370406 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-36bedc370406 -o br-36bedc370406 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m owner ! --uid-owner 117 -j LOGGING
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m owner ! --uid-owner 117 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 563 -m owner ! --uid-owner 117 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A DOCKER -d 172.31.0.2/32 ! -i br-36bedc370406 -o br-36bedc370406 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-36bedc370406 ! -o br-36bedc370406 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-36bedc370406 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Dropped: "
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jun 25 14:37:41 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Tue Jun 25 14:37:41 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m owner ! --uid-owner 117 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8888
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.31.0.0/16 ! -o br-36bedc370406 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.31.0.2/32 -d 172.31.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i br-36bedc370406 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -d 127.0.0.1/32 ! -i br-36bedc370406 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.31.0.2:3000
COMMIT

nft list ruleset shows:
table ip filter {
        chain INPUT {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
                meta l4proto tcp tcp dport { 80,443} counter packets 1642563 bytes 190179301 jump f2b-apache-fakegooglebot
                meta l4proto tcp tcp dport { 80,443} counter packets 9116728 bytes 1069624630 jump f2b-apache-auth
                meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 22 counter packets 413620 bytes 31257328 jump f2b-sshd
                meta l4proto tcp tcp dport { 110,995,143,993,587,465,4190} counter packets 6304246 bytes 659133161 jump f2b-dovecot
                meta l4proto tcp tcp dport { 25,465,587} counter packets 1358308 bytes 1357726201 jump f2b-postfix
                meta l4proto tcp tcp dport { 80,443,25,587,110,995,143,993,4190} counter packets 15403400 bytes 2939709444 jump f2b-postfix
                iifname "lo" counter packets 45927262 bytes 22275943601 accept
                ct state related,established counter packets 23416790 bytes 5815553538 accept
                iifname "eth0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 53 counter packets 5885 bytes 340579 accept
                iifname "eth0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 53 counter packets 895484 bytes 69357764 accept
                iifname "docker0" meta l4proto tcp counter packets 3001 bytes 180060 accept
                meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 21 ct state new,established # -m geoip --source-country GB,UG,KE,ZA  counter packets 49 bytes 2480 accept
                meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 20 ct state related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp tcp sport 1024-65535 tcp dport 1024-65535 ct state established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 12000-13000 counter packets 2973 bytes 135532 accept
                meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 12000-13000 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iifname "eth0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport { 25,110,143,465,587,993,995,2525,2526} counter packets 197174 bytes 11469412 accept
                iifname "eth0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport { 80,443} counter packets 787414 bytes 46406299 accept
                iifname "eth0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport { 22,873} # -m geoip --source-country GB  counter packets 275 bytes 15232 accept
                iifname "eth0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport { 8080,3100} # -m geoip --source-country GB  counter packets 143 bytes 6132 accept
                iifname "eth0" meta l4proto icmp counter packets 29321 bytes 1823925 accept
                counter packets 205049 bytes 10393170 jump SpamhausIN
        }

        chain LOGGING {
                limit rate 2/minute counter packets 24372 bytes 1259527 log prefix "IPTables-Dropped: "
        }
        chain FORWARD {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
                counter packets 91 bytes 19822 jump DOCKER-USER
                counter packets 91 bytes 19822 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
                oifname "docker0" ct state related,established counter packets 6 bytes 636 accept
                oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
                iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 6 bytes 390 accept
                iifname "docker0" oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                oifname "br-36bedc370406" ct state related,established counter packets 217 bytes 55250 accept
                oifname "br-36bedc370406" counter packets 6 bytes 360 jump DOCKER
                iifname "br-36bedc370406" oifname != "br-36bedc370406" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iifname "br-36bedc370406" oifname "br-36bedc370406" counter packets 6 bytes 360 accept
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump SpamhausIN
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
                type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
                oifname "lo" counter packets 45927236 bytes 22275941960 accept
                oifname "docker0" counter packets 53070 bytes 13526184 accept
                meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 443 skuid != 117 counter packets 137554 bytes 6981510 jump LOGGING
                meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 443 skuid != 117 counter packets 137554 bytes 6981510 reject
                meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 563 skuid != 117 counter packets 6 bytes 312 reject
                meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 21 ct state new counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
                counter packets 32097922 bytes 38886685465 jump SpamhausOUT
        }

        chain f2b-dovecot {
                counter packets 128626 bytes 13891673 return
        }

        chain DOCKER {
        }
      chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 {
                iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
                iifname "br-36bedc370406" oifname != "br-36bedc370406" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        }

        chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 {
                oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
                oifname "br-36bedc370406" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        }

        chain DOCKER-USER {
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        }
}
table ip nat {
        chain OUTPUT {
                type nat hook output priority -100; policy accept;
                meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 80 skuid != 117 counter packets 2 bytes 120 redirect to :8888
                ip daddr != 127.0.0.0/8 fib daddr type local counter packets 8 bytes 480 jump DOCKER
        }

        chain POSTROUTING {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                oifname != "docker0" ip saddr 172.17.0.0/16 counter packets 3 bytes 195 masquerade 
                oifname != "br-36bedc370406" ip saddr 172.31.0.0/16 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade 
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 172.31.0.2 ip daddr 172.31.0.2 tcp dport 3000 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade 
        }

        chain PREROUTING {
                type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
                fib daddr type local counter packets 2221 bytes 148479 jump DOCKER
        }

        chain DOCKER {
                iifname "docker0" counter packets 3 bytes 180 return
                iifname "br-36bedc370406" counter packets 7 bytes 420 return
                iifname != "br-36bedc370406" meta l4proto tcp ip daddr 127.0.0.1 tcp dport 3000 counter packets 0 bytes 0 dnat to 172.31.0.2:3000
        }
}
table ip6 nat {
        chain OUTPUT {
                type nat hook output priority -100; policy accept;
                meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 80 skuid != 117 counter packets 35400 bytes 2832000 redirect to :8888
        }

        chain DOCKER {
        }
}



Output from host:~$ ip route (ip isn't on the container):
default via 185.x.x.1 dev eth0 proto static onlink 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
172.31.0.0/16 dev br-36bedc370406 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.0.1 
185.x.x.0/22 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 185.x.x.83 

~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:00:00:00:40:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 185.x.x.83/22 brd 185.x.x.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 185.x.x.59/22 brd 185.x.x.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001:xxx:x:xxx::3b/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001:xxx:x:xxx::53/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ff:fe00:4017/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:91:dc:5d:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:91ff:fedc:5d95/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: vethf05d58a@if9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether 6a:7e:2f:5d:df:f3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 2
    inet6 fe80::687e:2fff:fe5d:dff3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
102: br-36bedc370406: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:da:79:75:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.0.1/16 brd 172.31.255.255 scope global br-36bedc370406
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:daff:fe79:75ae/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
104: vetheec212b@if103: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-36bedc370406 state UP group default 
    link/ether 1e:4a:34:89:98:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::1c4a:34ff:fe89:98cf/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
110: veth216a525@if109: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-36bedc370406 state UP group default 
    link/ether 4e:15:61:92:30:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::4c15:61ff:fe92:30a0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

host:~$ docker network ls shows this:
NETWORK ID     NAME             DRIVER    SCOPE
1f2cb04b3b54   bridge           bridge    local
c9ea0692db1b   host             host      local
a91ee892376d   none             null      local
36bedc370406   rallly_default   bridge    local

The network used by the container in question is called "rallly_default".
host:~$ docker network inspect rallly_default
{
        "Name": "rallly_default",
        "Id": "36bedc3704069d8d2ad6cc02031296a5fadb95ca988ee1a0e9d461b5e6ba083b",
        "Created": "2024-06-24T20:59:40.356497842Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.31.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.31.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "4c41cdd942d82c1504804fbf94e3980ef96adaabbec43ae36ac8ec21c255d970": {
                "Name": "rallly-rallly_db-1",
                "EndpointID": "1f7352607a1062ddb6ae421b490bb12739a099476137396737a1a60b752e67d0",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1f:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.31.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "rallly",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.27.1"
        }
    }
]


Show your exact configuration for network interfaces and DNS resolution of the hostnames involved.

Can you be more specific? What command outputs would you be wanting?

Since you say that connections to the smtp server from the host are working correctly, I would be interested in seeing the output of ip route on the host as well as the output of something like tcpump -nn -i any host 182.xx.xx.59 when attempting to connect from inside the container.

The connection on port 587 from the container appears to go to the web interface A, but I'm not sure. sounds like you need to validate the address that the name resolved to.

If Postfix literally binds to an interface (instead of listening to only an address configured on a certain interface),  AFAIK it would mean that it will not receive traffics from another interface. (Assuming your container is connected to a bridge, Postfix would need to be receiving traffics from the bridge interface.)

In other words, A (and even B in some sense) are not even relevant, unless they are the docker bridges. Or, if you are relying on hairpinning on some router B is connected to. (In that case you probably need to mess with policy routing, depending on the current routes on the host.)

@GregAskew they validate OK using getent hosts inside the container. @TomYan I mean Postfix is using smtp_bind_address = 185.x.x.59 The container is not using a bridge but a custom network config (this isn't my app I'm afraid - I'm just trying to get it to work on my system).

@TommyPeanuts Well, can the container reach host at all in general (like ping on any of its address)? (Could be the firewall on the host side.) Also, you should still be able to know or even change what type of network it uses (host? macvlan?). Are you given a compose file or what?

@TomYan Yes, it's able to proxy to Apache via the web IP (as explained in my question). And while ping isn't on the container, gentent resolves everything fine (again, as explained). BTW I've changed the network type in docker-compose to host and bridge but that cuts it off completely.

@TommyPeanuts in your ip route output there are only routes of one interface (excluding the docker bridges); please add the output of ip a instead

@TommyPeanuts Okay so you don't actually have multiple interfaces, but multiple IPs configured on a single interface. It shouldn't cause a problem though, especially when Postfix is bound to one of the addresses. Either way, you probably want to check with something like tcpdump -eni any port 587 on the host and see how the received traffics look and whether any replies are even emitted from Postfix. I still think that it could be a firewall thing, so I'd recommend that you also add outputs of iptables-save and nft list ruleset to your post.

tcpdump shows packets on port 587 coming from the container, but not coming back from the mail server that does sound like a firewall thing to me (seeing the request in tcpdump does NOT mean that it didn't get filtered).

I should point out that I have other containers (for other apps) sending out mail on port 587 perfectly fine, so doubt any of this is related to what's going on in the host. But I've posted what you asked for.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

As you can see yourself, your filter/INPUT policy is DROP, and tcp port 587 is only opened for traffics from eth0 (while in the case of concern, the request comes from br-36bedc370406). At the same time, all traffics from the default docker bridge docker0 is accepted (which may explain the case of other containers, assuming they are not started with docker compose).
Apparently your are maintaining a firewall with iptables (or some frontend that uses the iptables program) while it is a variant that actually translates rules / commands into nftables rules. Therefore, you can continue to do so (and ignore the outputs of nft / just consider yourself using iptables).
I'm not sure what's the best practice here though. You may add a rule that open tcp port 587 for all interfaces (i.e., no -i test in the rule), or maybe see if you can find a way to specify a fixed bridge name in the compose file. (IIRC by default the bridge name will change if you perform a compose down/up cycle, but I don't really know/remember. Similarly the private IP subnet may not necessarily be the same block every time, but of course that's a bit more pseudo-deterministic.) Ultimately it depends on what kind of filtering / "protection" you really need.

Ah, thanks. Opening up port 587 on all interfaces indeed cures the problem. I might see if I can exclude the web IP from that though, but that's just an iptables issue.

@TommyPeanuts You can certainly add a -d test, but I am not so sure it would actually have a point.
